# (Java) What kind of argument is this? With a

Tags: java, oop

Please can anybody explain, I found this in a program on the Internet. I googled it up but nothing helped as I don't know what it is called?

Why are there three dots(...) after String in the argument?
Please Explain.

```
public static void MakePro(String... visual) 
{
..
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function

Comment: oh thanks, I think the answer by user is helpful, wikipedia never helper in code

Comment: this has been answered many times before, please search for varargs

Comment: @RonakJain If OP did not know what it was called, how would they know to search for varargs?

Comment: @BJMyers because I told him what it is called. See the first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varargs  (Variable Arguments)
Varargs (introduced in Java SE 5) allows you to pass 0, 1, or more params to a method's vararg param.
They let you pass any number of objects of a specific type.This reduces the need for overloading methods that do the similar things. For example,

```
public static void AsSimpleAsThis(String... params) 
// params represents a vararg. 
{
}
```

AsSimpleAsThis(s1,s2,s3); // pass 3 strings

params[0] is the first string

params[1] is the second string

params[2] is the third string

```
AsSimpleAsThis("hello",s2); // pass 2 strings
```

params[0] is the first string (="hello")

params[1] is the second string

```
AsSimpleAsThis("hey")
```

params[0] is the first string=hey

The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final argument may be passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments. Varargs can be used only in the final argument position.

Comment: oh ok, now I understand a little bit, can U tell me where are these used?

Comment: It simply allows a function to handle a number of parameters